# Can I leave my house during the 14 days of self-isolation if I have to take a flight out of UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, residency, covid-19, italy-aire

On December the 3rd I will go back in the UK from Italy and, if the rules stay the same, I'll have to self-isolate for 14 days in UK.

Does this mean that I cannot leave the house not even to go to the airport to take a flight back to Italy before the 14 days have elapsed?

My plan would be to come back in Italy on December the 16th, which is before the 14 days have elapsed.

I am Italian and resident in the UK for work.

Comment: That will probably depend on the circumstances, which you haven't supplied in the question. [Foreign travel advice - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice): From 5 November to 2 December 2020, travelling away from home, **including internationally**, *is restricted* from England except in limited circumstances such as for work or for education.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, what circumstance should I supply? I've added the day when I will land in UK (Dec the 3rd). Do you think anything else is needed?

Comment: Assuming you are a UK resident, returning to the UK should pose no problem. It is a question after your arrival (and quarantine), that you wish to travel **again**. For the UK this is now *restricted*, in other countries it is somewhere between *discouraged* to **essential only**. So you must supply the **reason/purpose** of your travel abroad. For **essential** travel, they determine if the given reason is essential or not.

Comment: See [Italy - FAQ - Covid-19, questions and answers](http://www.salute.gov.it/portale/nuovocoronavirus/dettaglioFaqNuovoCoronavirus.jsp?lingua=english&id=230#8) and [Italian nationals returning to Italy and foreigners in Italy](https://www.esteri.it/mae/en/ministero/normativaonline/decreto-iorestoacasa-domande-frequenti/focus-cittadini-italiani-in-rientro-dall-estero-e-cittadini-stranieri-in-italia.html)

Comment: Without knowing the reason (or wanting to judge) for this 13 days trip, is this **truly essential**? The goal of these measures is to avoid (possible) **spreading** from one area to another. The advice in Italy: it *is strongly recommended to refrain from travelling* within Italy.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, There are reason why I'd rather stay in Italy all the time (one of those being that I feel more protected in my home country than in UK), but unfortunately I cannot (because of some financial/taxation things that I can't get explained to me by thouse who should). Therefore I am **considering** the plans I described in the question. Probably I will give up, but in the meanwhile I'm trying to understand what the odds are for me to be able to travel without incurring 10000£ fine, so that I can decide if it makes sense to buy a flight which is still cheap.

Comment: @Traveller link shows an exception for: *you are travelling directly in order to leave England*, so on this account your planned intinerary seems fine. But will you be able to deal with your `finantial/taxation things` while in isolation at home?

Comment: @MarkJohnson, I would cover that with holidays. But again, I'm just trying to picture in my mind the possible scenarios before wasting money or risking my heath.

Comment: I think you misunderstood: to deal with your affair you probably have to meet with other peaple. That will be a problem if you need to meet them personally. You would have to stay longer than 14 days for that.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, I expressed myself in a terrible way. What I mean is that I've been told I need to stay physically in the UK and not in Italy (even though I work remotely in both cases), despite the [183 days rule](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/162782/117752) that is written in [Statutory Residence Test (SRT)](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/rdr3-statutory-residence-test-srt/guidance-note-for-statutory-residence-test-srt-rdr3). So I don't need to meet anyone. I just need to make someone happy by staying in UK while working.

Comment: > I expressed myself in a terrible way. What I mean is that I've been told I need to stay physically in the UK and not in Italy (even though I work remotely in both cases), despite the [183 days][0] rule that is written in [Statutory Residence Test (SRT)][1]. So I don't need to meet anyone. I just need to make someone happy by staying in UK while working. I would suggest **asking a new question** if any of the following may apply to your situation (thus avoiding a return soly to fullfill the last few days of the 183 days requirement) from [RDR3: Statutory Residence Test (SRT) notes - GOV.UK][1

Answer (score 3):

If you’re travelling to the UK for less than 14 days, you will be expected to self-isolate for the length of your stay, but you can travel directly to your place of departure.

Exceptions from remaining at your place of self-isolation include where:

- you are travelling directly in order to leave England.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/coronavirus-covid-19-how-to-self-isolate-when-you-travel-to-the-uk/coronavirus-covid-19-how-to-self-isolate-when-you-travel-to-the-uk

Edit:  You are supposed to go straight to your destination **and** minimise your use of public transport; if for example a walk to the nearest station + train to the airport is your only option and your reason for taking that route is to leave the UK, the rules allow you to leave your self-isolation location before the 14 days are up and travel. But you can’t stop off along the way eg to go shopping or eat in a café. See the section on “How to travel to the place where you are self-isolating” - the rules apply in both directions

Comment: It doesn't sound like the exception includes the scenario of going to UK, staying there for, say, 10 days, and then going back to the place.

Comment: @Enrico I don’t follow you. If you read the rules set out on the page I linked to, someone visiting the UK for less than 14 days must self-isolate in one place for the entire period they are in the UK. At the end of that period, they can leave their self-isolation location to go directly to their place of departure from the UK (airport, port, Channel tunnel).

Comment: Oh, I misread that, sorry! As regards the _directly_ part, would that mean that I cannot break the travel to my destination in multiple pieces (e.g., walk to train station, take train to airport, take flight to destination)?

Comment: @Enrico I think you are interpreting ‘directly’ too literally. You are supposed to minimise your use of public transport; if the three-part journey you describe is your only option to get to the airport **and** your reason for it is to leave the UK, the rules allow you to travel. But you can’t stop off along the way eg to go shopping or eat in a café. See the section on “How to travel to the place where you are self-isolating” - the rules apply in both directions